# Discord Guild and Members Cache

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So my bot is needing the Guild and its members to be cached, but I can't work out how to do it.  I'm also not sure if I would need to cache in this module (and any later ones that also need caching), or if I can cache in a central one (e.g. Config/Index) and just reference back later on.    Advice needed, please!

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('../settings/config.js');
const client = require('../index.js').client;
const Guild_ID = require('../settings/configuration').BOT_SETTINGS;
const totalUsers = client.channels.fetch('883654989271154728');
const onlineUsers = client.channels.fetch('883655041813200926');
const onlineStaff = client.channels.fetch('883655107902844978');

let guild = client.guilds.fetch('867657498827948032')
.then(guild => console.log(guild.name))
.catch(console.error);

setInterval(function() {
console.log('Getting stats update..')

var userCount = client.memberCount;
var onlineCount = guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.presence.status === 'online').size
var coderCount = client.roles.get('867673073440391188').members.size;

console.log("Total Users: " + userCount);
console.log("Online Users: " + onlineCount);
console.log("Online Staff: " + coderCount);

totalUsers.setName("Total Users: " + userCount)
.then(newChannel => console.log(`Stat channel renamed to: ${newChannel.name}`))
.catch(console.error);

onlineUsers.setName("Online Users: " + onlineCount)
.then(newChannel => console.log(`Stat channel renamed to: ${newChannel.name}`))
.catch(console.error);

onlineStaff.setName("Online Staff: " + coderCount)
.then(newChannel => console.log(`Stat channel renamed to: ${newChannel.name}`))
.catch(console.error);
}, 30000)
```

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` returns a promise which must be resolved. Whenever using `.then()` to resolve promises, the result is available inside the callback function.

However the there is no need to fetch channels if you have the guild object, they will be cached.

You must either use `async/await` or work inside of `.then()`. I also recommend fetching all of your GuildMembers to cache them all (this will require the guild members intent to be enabled)

To make it easier on us I'll use async/await, wrapping your code inside an `update` function.

```js
async function update() {
   try {
      const guild = await client.guilds.fetch('867657498827948032');

      const totalUsers = guild.channels.cache.get('883654989271154728');
      const onlineUsers = guild.channels.cache.get('883655041813200926');
      const onlineStaff = guild.channels.cache.get('883655107902844978');

      const guildMembers = await guild.members.fetch();

      var onlineCount = guildMembers.filter(m => m.presence.status === 'online').size;

      // Access the role via the guild object
      var coderCount = guild.roles.cache.get('867673073440391188').members.size;

      // Update channel name code...
   } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
   }
}

setInterval(update, 30000);
```

Note: As this function runs every 30 seconds, and multiple data are being fetched. This is considered API spam. I recommend either refactoring your function or increasing the interval significantly